# Staking in python?

Tags: python, staking, solana-py

I'm currently trying to use [this](https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/pull/345) branch of Solana-py to create a script which allows me to automatically find the best validator and stake my SOL with it.

I'm having an issue when trying to pass the stake transaction, where it's saying there are not enough signers. I would imagine this has something to do with [the solana cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/staking.html#create-stake-account) saying I need 2 signers (the owner of the SOL and the stake account). But, the code i'm using to stake with doesnt give the keypair which with I would sign this transaction.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: share your code please

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find an answer using [this PR](https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/pull/345) and used it to cobble a solution together. I would suggest for anyone that stumbles onto this to do the same, as my code is relatively specialized so not likely to be useful to anyone.

The one note from my question

> How can i create the stake account

Yes, you do need the private key of the stake account, but you're not using the same type of account that the `create_account()` method from solders creates, you need to create a blank account, which you can then throw away the keypair for after signing.

Comment: Could you paste some code for your solution still? It may be helpful to others